# CRM 2011: Display the Body of an Email In Another Entity

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

Can I show the body (description) of an email in a custom entity?
I have tried to copy the content of the description field into a field in the custom entity, but end up with all the formatting showing.
What about putting an iFrame of the email on the custom entity form and then manipulating the email until it only show the email description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body of an email is html. If you put the content in a control of CRM will not formatted. You can put in a iframe (html page) or a web resource of type html and put only the body of the email. This solution permits don't occupying so much space as your solution.

Comment: Thanks Pedro, that works. The only problem is that the images do not come through, it shows cid:image001.jpg... where the image was in the email. Any ideas on how to get the images to come through?

Comment: I don't know but this reference for the image refer to an attachment. The only thing i see is you have another html controls that show this pictures.